# IF Statement with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, if-statement, clearinterval

I've got a countdown app that's running multiple dates. I want to run the clearInterval(), when each one reaches the date and stop the clock.

I have my current date and stored dates:

```
const currentDate = new Date()

const stageOneA = new Date ('March 8, 2021 00:00:00'),
stageOneB = new Date('March 29,2021 00:00:00'),
stageTwo = new Date('April 12, 2021 00:00:00'),
stageThree = new Date('March 3,2021 00:00:00'),
stageFour = new Date('June 21,2021 00:00:00').getTime()
```

Then I want to write an IF statement to check if the currentDate is less or equal to each date, then call the clearInterval. This works for one variable, but not for all of them.

I thought the below would work but it doesn't. Where am I going wrong?

```
if(stageOneA || stageOneB || stageTwo || stageThree || stageFour <= currentDate) {
    clearInterval(updateCountdown)
 }
```

Comment: `stageOneA` will always be truthy, the rest will never be checked, the `if` statement always passes. You’re not properly comparing multiple values with `currentDate`.

Comment: If you store the date objects in a data structure such as an array, you can sort them. You only ever need to check the first or last item in the array depending on the sort order. For example if it's not yet `'March 8, 2021 00:00:00'` then there is no need to check `'March 29,2021 00:00:00'`, `'April 12, 2021 00:00:00'` etc. Remove the element from the array once the time point is reached/has passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common mistake, and it makes sense it make it.

The correct code is probably the best way to explain:

```js
if (stageOneA <= currentDate ||
    stageOneB <= currentDate ||
    stageTwo <= currentDate ||
    stageThree <= currentDate ||
    stageFour <= currentDate) 
{

    clearInterval(updateCountdown);
}
```

You must check every single stage on its own.

What your original code is saying is check if the first 4 dates exist then checking whether `stageFour` is less than or equal to the current date.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your if statement to read better, you can create a little helper

```
const stages = [stageOneA, stageOneB, stageTwo, stageThree, stageFour];
const olderThan = date => stage => stage <= date;

if(stages.some(olderThan(currentDate))) {
   clearInterval(updateCountdown);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Our interval
const interval = setInterval(() => console.log('lalala'), 1000);

// Declare array of times
const times = [
  new Date ('March 8, 2021 00:00:00'),
  new Date('March 29,2021 00:00:00'),
  new Date('April 12, 2021 00:00:00'),
  new Date('March 3,2021 00:00:00'),
  new Date('June 21,2021 00:00:00'),
];



// Here begins the checking part.
// This would presumably be ran in a loop,
// perhaps in the same interval function?

// Declare the time we are checking against
const othertime = new Date();
// not needed if we want to just use Date.now()

// check against 
if (
  // use times.reduce to get earliest time
  times.reduce(
    // times.reduce is passed a function
    // that takes a and b as arguments
    (a, b) => (
      // check which time is smaller
      ( a.getTime() < a.getTime() )
      // and return that
      ? a : b
    )
    // compare the smallest time to the time we're checking against
  ).getTime() < othertime.getTime()
  // instead of othertime.getTime(), we can use Date.now()
) {
  // do whatever
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: This isn't anything like what the OP was asking about?

Comment: @JayHales I do believe it is a more complete solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: That may be, but the question is about if statements, not the whole code.